# Can you export Ruby-Processing sketches?

Tags: java, android, ruby, processing

Is there a way to export Ruby-Processing sketches as Android projects or Java applets like you can in PDE?

Comment: Have you tried this? https://github.com/jashkenas/ruby-processing/wiki/Exporting-Applications

Comment: As ruby-processing is not widely used (among the Processing community at least) you will have better luck asking on their specific forums or the github page or perhaps here: http://learning-ruby-processing.blogspot.com.ar If you do get an answer elsewhere, you can provide an answer to your own question. I'm sure people'd like to know if its possible to do what you're asking here.